# SWF file stops playing on unplugging the charger from laptop

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, flash

My problem might seem odd.I have created a windows service which when starts,plays a swf file.The swf file does work and everything works just fine.The only problem is,the file closes as soon as I unplug my charger,and my laptop starts running on battery,the player stops and the window closes.The service doesn't stop,it's just the window that gets closed.I have followed the following steps to start an swf file from my service.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110568/Alternative-way-for-Window-services-to-interact-wi
Does anybody has an answer as to this quirky behaviour or what is causing this?I'll be happy to provide more samples from my code if the code in above link is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

TaskDefinition.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries=false.
It is true by default.